# JavaFX remove window flicker on first mouse click anywhere after launch

Tags: javafx

Using jdk-17.jdk,  javafx-sdk-17.0.7, Mac OS  Sonoma 14.1.1, IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3.3.

Any JavaFX app I write has this issue:

After launching the app, the first user mouse click anywhere within the app results in the entire window flickering once. Then it is fine - no more flickering.

Here is a simple HelloWorld app as an example:

```
package com.example.javafxdemo;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class HelloWorld extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
        btn.setOnAction(event -> System.out.println("Hello World!"));

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(btn);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

This has the flickering issue.
TIA.

Comment: Yes, occurs also when running from the command line.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include Java/FX vendors, as well as versions; someone may be able to reproduce your result.

Comment: Try a recent version of JavaFX e.g. 21.0.1 (which had some fixes specifically for Sonoma support) and, similarly, a 21+ version of the JDK.  Ensure that you are using the right versions of JavaFX and the JDK for your architecture (e.g. an M series Mac requires an aarch64 version of the software, whereas an Intel series Mac requires an x64 version of the software).